# blender displacement working wrong im trying to make heightmap from terrain

Tags: displacement

1) i added plane and divide it 8x8 grid.
2) i just pull up most middle four vertex to test result.
3) i created new image 9x9 pixel at UV/Image Editor
4) When Top Ortho , i unwrap it with ( Project from View Bounds )

and i am trying to take heightmap (bake heightmap) but it is giving this result :

[image]

how can i take this result :

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should extrude this place rather than grab?

Comment: also your texture seems to be 9x9 pixels and your mesh has an 8x8 grid, sure he needs to somehow interpolate?

Comment: when i make 8x8 texture again same result :(

Comment: @SergeL i didnt understand you sorry for my bad english but if you say change mesh (terrain) i dont want to change

Comment: Well, select desired area of you terrain and create new vertex group for it. Then add Mask modifier to terrain and select this vertex group. This will cut all extra geometry for baking process and won't affect original mesh.